# InvalidArgumentError in Keras embedding; works in Python3.6 on Windows, not on Mac

Tags: python, keras

I have a CNN that I made using character embedding on my windows 10 machine using python 3.6 and keras 2.2.0. I put that same version on my mac, and whether I use python 2.7 or 3.6, I get an embedding error.

My embedding layer uses an input dim of 101, which is the size of my weights matrix; I also use zero masking. Everything works perfectly within windows, but on my mac, when it gets to a character that is indexed at 101, I get the following error:

`InvalidArgumentError: indices[26,6] = 101 is not in [0, 101)`

Any ideas what is going on, and what I can do about it?

more details: here is info about the weights matrix and how I use it

```
weights.shape = (101,101)
inputs=L.Input(shape=(length,))                                 `
embedding=L.Embedding(input_dim=weights.shape[0],
                      output_dim=weights.shape[1],
                      input_length=length,
                      weights=[weights],
                      mask_zero=True,trainable=False)(inputs)
```

The error:

> InvalidArgumentError: indices[31,60] = 101 is not in [0, 101)
>
> [[Node: embedding_2/embedding_lookup = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32,
> Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT,
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_2/embeddings/read,
> embedding_2/Cast, embedding_2/embedding_lookup/axis)]]

Comment: Are you using GPU on windows? Out of range indexing does not raise error with TF-gpu if I remember correctly.

Comment: Why yes, I am. I guess I should refrain with a weights file that is one larger. Just sucks because I spent a lot of time getting the one I have in hand. :-(